# How to display a unserialised data in php when there are multiple values in an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table

I have a page which shows data from a database which has a **unserialized** data. The unserialized data looks like that:

```
array (
  'text-name' => 'test',
  'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
  'text-company' => 'test',
  'tel-number' => '978456132',
  'products' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Domains',
    1 => 'Weebly',
  ),
  'menu-country' => 'Austria',
  'number' => '1001 - 10,000',
  'text-current-registrar' => '5',
  'notes' => 'test',
  'text-current-url' => 'https://www.foo.com/boo-foo/',
  'text-previous-url' => 'https://www.foo.com/boo-foo/',
  'text-utm_source' => '',
  'text-utm_medium' => '',
  'text-utm_campaign' => '',
  'gdpr-b' => 
  array (
    0 => 'I',
  ),
  'gdpr-c' => 
  array (
    0 => 'I',
  ),
  'gdpr-d' => NULL,
  'gdpr-e' => NULL,
)
```

the data in the DB is in this format: `'a:18:{s:9:"text-name";s:4:"test";s:5:"email";s:14:"test@gmail.com";s:12:"text-company";s:4:"test";s:10:"tel-number";s:9:"978456132";s:8:"products";a:2:{i:0;s:7:"Domains";i:1;s:6:"Weebly";}s:12:"menu-country";s:7:"Austria";s:6:"number";s:13:"1001 - 10,000";s:22:"text-current-registrar";s:1:"5";s:5:"notes";s:4:"test";s:16:"text-current-url";s:59:"https://www.bla.com/foo-bar/";s:17:"text-previous-url";s:59:"https://www.bla.com/foo-bar/";s:15:"text-utm_source";s:0:"";s:15:"text-utm_medium";s:0:"";s:17:"text-utm_campaign";s:0:"";s:6:"gdpr-b";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"I";}s:6:"gdpr-c";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"I";}s:6:"gdpr-d";N;s:6:"gdpr-e";N;}'`

the php code to display is as follows:

```
<?php
        $no     = 1;        
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {           
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['form'].'</td>';           
             $formdata = unserialize($row['data']);
            foreach ($formdata as $key => $fdata)
            {
                if( sizeof($fdata) !=1  ) 
                {
                    if (is_array($fdata)) {
                        $fsofdata = array_map('unserialize', $fdata);
                        foreach ($fsofdata as $prod => $prodvalue)
                        {
                            if ( ($prod === 'gdpr-b') || ($prod === 'gdpr-c') || ($prod === 'gdpr-d') || ($prod === 'gdpr-d')  ) {
                                foreach ($prodvalue as $pprod => $pprodvalue)
                                {
                                    echo '<td>'.$pprod.''.($pprodvalue).'</td>';
                                }
                            }
                            else {


                            echo '<td>'.($prodvalue).'</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<td>'.($fdata).'<td/>';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td>'.($fdata).'<td/>';                                                   
                }
            }
            echo '<td>'.$row['date']. '</td>';                  
            echo '</tr>';           
            $no++;
        }
?>
```

The problem here is that the data which is present inside the products array and the gdpr-b, gdpr-c variables are showing as array i tried array_map on the data but that too didnt help how do i display the values in the array in the table.

Comment: can you please print product array and send here

Comment: when I print the array  on the screen its 'Array'

Comment: then better you use foreach there

Comment: there is something wrong with the table relation or your logic find that first

Comment: I'm storing this data from a different plugin altogether. so I don't have  control  for the database values

Comment: ok tell me one thing how you want to display the multiple products in a single column

Comment: it would be in one <td> for eg:   `<td> Domains Weebly </td>`

Comment: but you are getting multiple product there right?  if you want to display that then use  $array[0]

Answer (score 0):

`serialize()` and `unserialize()` are dual - i.e. if you have an array and serialize it then unserialize will get you back the exact same array (including all nested sub-arrays).
However, if your original array contained elements which are the serialization of another arrays (so these elements are currently strings) - then you will have to iterate over your 1-st level array and unserialize each individual item.
The best approach is to serialize only the top-level array as a whole - not each of its items.
And if your array does not contain objects - it is much better to use `json_encode` and `json_decode`

Comment: The original array is serialized I cannot use json_decode as the data inside it is not a proper json.

Comment: if the result of `serialize($original_array)` was stored in the DB - then you will get the array back by simply doing `unserialize($string_from_DB)`